# Possible bug in Postsharp ReturnValue Location aspects

Tags: postsharp

I've been working with PostSharp for a year now and recently moved to version 3, I've had a great deal of success with it. I'm attempting to widen it's adoption in our company and the killer feature for adoption will be multicasted contract attributes.

I've been looking into PostSharp.Patterns.Contracts and written MulticastAttributes for them but there are several things that cause friction when applying these aspects  to our legacy code, such as ArgumentNullException instead of ArgumentExceptions in some string validations but the most significant is that ReturnValues cannot use these attributes.

I have to double the number of aspects - one set for Parameters and one set with the same validations, albeit different exceptions, for ReturnValues using OnMethodBoundaryAspect - which is not acceptable to our developers, so I have been trying to develop a set of contracts that can be applied to both Parameters and Return Values.

I note that a LocationContractAttribute is derived directly from MulticastAttribute and only contains code to support various exceptions and their messages so it looks like a simple task to write my own but the following simple aspect gives an exception when Postsharp kicks in after compilation:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.ReturnValue),
    AspectConfiguration(SerializerType = typeof(MsilAspectSerializer)),
    MulticastAttributeUsage(
        MulticastTargets.ReturnValue
        , TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.NonAbstract
        , Inheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast
        , PersistMetaData = true
    )]
public class SimpleReturnValueAttribute: MulticastAttribute,
    ILocationValidationAspect<string>
{
    public Exception ValidateValue(string value, string locationName, LocationKind locationKind)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

to the class:

```
public class AspectTarget
{
        [return: SimpleReturnValue]
        public string ReturnEmptyString2()
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

gives the exception:

```
Error   1   Unhandled exception (3.0.26.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodDefDeclaration.^bvoT7mPt9PXI(Int32 _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.CanonicalMethodMapping.^X0NY.EmitLoadArgument(Int32 _0, InstructionWriter _1)
   at ^670BgLZZ9jB2.^X5f4d1Yo.Implement(MethodBodyTransformationContext _0)
   at ^EbCRMdujK27A.^LuETqvLKzZPB(MetadataDeclaration _0, MetadataDeclaration _1, MethodSemantics _2, InstructionBlock _3, Object[] _4, CanonicalMethodMapping _5, LocalVariableSymbol _6, InstructionSequence _7, TypeDefDeclaration _8, PipelineTransversalState _9)
   at ^PE9ycIe2cLwm.^HvVDHXOj(MetadataDeclaration _0, IDependencyTransformationInstance[] _1, PipelineTransversalState _2, MethodSemantics _3)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.AspectInfrastructureTask.^jwku0geZ(MetadataDeclaration _0, PipelineTransversalState _1, MethodSemantics _2, Boolean _3)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.AspectInfrastructureTask.^MwzbegST(IMetadataDeclaration _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^d+wOzSPF(IMetadataDeclaration _0, Func`2 _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^+g+TCqVg(TypeDefDeclaration _0, Func`2 _1, Set`1 _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^fJqG(Func`2 _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.AspectInfrastructureTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation)
```

Deriving the aspect from LocationLevelAspect gives the same error. I've also tried various values AspectConfiguration and PersistMetaData or omitting them altogether but I get the same exception.

Could do with some assistance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that `ILocationValidationAspect` cannot be applied to return values. This scenario is not supported, but instead of getting a nice error message, you get an exception.

Currently, return values must be validated using an `OnMethodBoundary` aspect (`OnSuccess` advise).

If you want to provide developers with a single custom attribute instead of two, you can have this single custom attribute implementing `IAspectProvider`, and have this aspect provide one of the two implementations.

Please use https://postsharp.uservoice.com/ to request this feature (ILocationValidationAspect should support return values).

Thanks.